# jQuery Replace not acting as expected

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

```js
$(".rowIWanTtoReplace").replaceWith("<tr><td rowspan='11' class='n'>n</td><td rowspan='8'>n</td><td>t</td><td>n</td></tr><tr><td>u</td><td>n</td></tr><tr><td>v</td><td>n</td></tr><tr><td>w</td><td>n</td></tr><tr><td>x</td><td>n</td></tr><tr><td>y</td><td>n</td></tr><tr><td>z</td><td>n</td></tr>");
```

```css
td {
  border: 1px solid black
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="station-device-table4">
        <tr>
            <td>x</td>
            <td>y</td>
            <td>z</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="rowIWanTtoReplace">
            <td rowspan="11" class="s">foobar</td>
            <td rowspan="7">foobar</td>
            <td>n</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

I just wanted to check whether or not this should be the result of a replaceWith() in this situation:

If I have a table and on one row I apply `replaceWith()`, And What I replace it with is multiple table rows.

Shouldn't that just affect the HTML so when displayed multiple should show in that section?

i.e ------ TR 1 -----------

```
.replaceWith("<tr>x</tr><tr>y</tr>")
```

shouldn't the first row replace the other row. And the second row append after?

Or is there an alternative method?

Thanks.

Example code for situation:

```
<table class="station-device-table4">
        <tr>
            <td>x</td>
            <td>y</td>
            <td>z</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="rowIWanTtoReplace">
            <td rowspan="11" class="s">foobar</td>
            <td rowspan="7">foobar</td>
            <td>n</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

JQuery example:

```
$(".rowIWanTtoReplace").replaceWith("<tr>
        <td rowspan="11" class="n">n</td>
        <td rowspan="8">n</td>
        <td>t</td>
        <td>n</td>
    </tr>
    <tr><td>u</td><td>n</td></tr>
    <tr><td>v</td><td>n</td></tr>
    <tr><td>w</td><td>n</td></tr>
    <tr><td>x</td><td>n</td></tr>
    <tr><td>y</td><td>n</td></tr>
    <tr><td>z</td><td>n</td></tr>")
```

Note: This is made from backbone collections and stuff. I have outputted to the screen the html that it using to update. And put the code together as if it was normal jquery.

Comment: Please click the `<>` button and provide a [mcve]

Comment: your "example code" doesn't even compile. Check your browser console for errors.

Comment: 2 seconds sorry

Comment: Selector strings can not span multiple lines. You can't nest `"` within `"`. You are replacing a `<th>` with `<tr>`s

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/9z4zcgob/ would work and also produce valid HTML. Note the change to where the header1 class is defined. Your version makes no sense, as per Turnip's observations

Comment: I made you a real snippet, then you deleted it. Please make a snippet

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/9z4zcgob/1/ as per your latest code. Again you need single quotes round the string in replceWith (to cope with the double quotes you want to use within it), and not to separate it across multiple lines

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot have linefeeds in strings unless you use [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) - also you had nested double quotes which also does not work.
In the original code you replaced a header cell with a table row which also did not compute.

This might be what you want:

```js
$(".rowIWanTtoReplace").replaceWith(`<tr>
        <td rowspan="11" class="tvmStatus">TVM Status</td>
        <td rowspan="8">Component Events</td>
        <td>t</td>
        <td>n</td>
    </tr>
    <tr><td>u</td><td>n</td></tr>
    <tr><td>v</td><td>n</td></tr>
    <tr><td>w</td><td>n</td></tr>
    <tr><td>x</td><td>n</td></tr>
    <tr><td>y</td><td>n</td></tr>
    <tr><td>z</td><td>n</td></tr>`)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="station-device-table4">
        <tr>
            <td>x</td>
            <td>y</td>
            <td>z</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="rowIWanTtoReplace">
            <td rowspan="11" class="s">foobar</td>
            <td rowspan="7">foobar</td>
            <td>n</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

Comment: What if the Jquery is happening through backbone like this: this.$el.html(this.template(this.model.attributes));

Comment: I have no idea. I do not use BackBone and the question is not tagged backbone

Comment: Then the $(a).replaceWith(``). I don't seem to have control over.

Comment: Sorry. I didn't think it would matter. I thought the JQuery would be the same.

Comment: Please update the question with the correct tags and describe your actual situation instead of making us guess

Comment: Thank you. You've answered my question though. So I'll find a way to achieve this through backbone.